# Sets of interviews for estimator position over phone with Dubai company?

Tags: interviewing, resume

I am wondering what your thoughts are on this set of interviews I had with a company in Dubai.

1. Interviewed in person 1v1 with a manager referred by friend, pretty casual in a hotel area, in Jordan
2. returned to USA, heard from HR requested salary and time to speak.
3. spoke with head of contracts (chief estimator?) over phone for 30 minutes, asked many (20+) personal and technical construction questions, it went well.
4. I sent a thank you for speaking followup, company sounds promising, look forward to hearing to which he replied hr will get back to you after checking all applicants
5. 2 weeks later, HR manager emails, we setup phone call, but this call went quick only two questions both unrelated, what kind of projects did you work on? what is your salary range? and said he will get back to me in a week.

Now what kind of follow-up do I send if any? how do the steps taken so far sound in gaining the position?

Comment: The last interview looked weird. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

> Now what kind of follow-up do I send if any?

Wait a week. If you haven't heard from them, just send a normal follow-up note indicating your continued interest.

Something similar to what you said before: "Thank you for speaking with me again... I'm very interested in working with you... I look forward to hearing from you..."

> how do the steps taken so far sound in gaining the position?

They sound promising, and typical for this sort of situation.